# cant insert into custom table using wpdb

Tags: wordpress

I created a custom table for my WordPress plug-in and called it "recp_clients". Not sure if it matters but I did NOT us a prefix of "wp_".

In my php file that processes some form data, rather than using the old style of connecting via "mysql_connect" et al, I wanted to use $wpdb to insert the post data.

Problem is it's not working.

**EDIT:** *Not sure if it matters but this code is inside of a php file that resides inside of a folder called includes that is inside of my main plugin folder. The file is called from a .js file using ajax. Not sure if that has anything to do with why $wpdb is not working but figured I'd add this info if it was important.*

Here is what I have:

```
$hisname=$_POST['hisname'];
$hername=$_POST['hername'];
$lastname=$_POST['lastname'];

global $wpdb

$wpdb->insert('recp_clients', array('client_hisname' => $hisname, 'client_hername' => $hername, 'client_lastname' => $lastname));
```

I also tried this:

```
$hisname=$_POST['hisname'];
$hername=$_POST['hername'];
$lastname=$_POST['lastname'];

global $wpdb
$recp_clients_table = $wpdb->prefix . ‘recp_clients’;

$wpdb->insert($recp_clients_table, array('client_hisname' => $hisname, 'client_hername' => $hername, 'client_lastname' => $lastname));
```

Any help is very much appreciated. Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the WHERE clause. Unless you are updating all rows with the same data, you need this. It might be that WP will not run the query if this is not included.

```
$wpdb->update(
  'recp_clients', 
  array(
    'client_hisname' => $hisname, 
    'client_hername' => $hername, 
    'client_lastname' => $lastname),
  array('id' => '54') // This is your WHERE clause
);
```

Comment: I'm an idiot. This should have been an insert statement, not update. As an insert statement it's not working as listed above.

Comment: Is ´hisname=$_POST['hisname'];´ a typo here? You are missing the $

Comment: Yes, I guess it didn't come over when I copied and pasted the code from my file. Fixed.

Comment: Not sure if it matters but this code is inside of a php file that resides inside of a folder called includes that is inside of my main plugin folder. The file is called from a .js file using ajax. Not sure if that has anything to do with why $wpdb is not working but figured I'd add that.

Comment: So doing a ´print_r($wpdb)´ gives you nothing? In that case, you need to include the WP header. Read more a bout that  here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website

Comment: The file is part of my plug-in, so would I still need to do that?

Comment: Not really. But if $wpdb is not working (or any other WP function) you can give it a go. Otherwise, the `$wpdb->insert`is pretty straight forward and I can't see any problems with your code.

Comment: Thanks for trying Steven. I tried what you suggested but alas it didn't work. Oh well, I'll keep searching.